# Show that differentiability at a point implies symmetric differentiability at a point.

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

> **Definition** Let $c \in (a, b)$ and let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is *symmetrically differentiable* at $c$ if $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + h) - f(c - h)}{2h}$$ exists and is finite.
>
> **Problem** Show that if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f$ is symmetrically differentiable at $c$, and the derivatives are the same.

I'm not entirely sure where to start. We want to show that, given $f'(c)$ exists, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + h) - f(c - h)}{2h} = f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + h) - f(c)}{h}$$
but I'm not sure how to do that. Can anyone provide minimal assistance? This seems like such a simple problem, but I'm stuck nonetheless. Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Make a change of variable and notice that $h\to 0$ if and only if $2h\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)+f(c)-f(c-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left[f(c+h)-f(c)\right]-\left[f(c-h)-f(c)\right]}{2h}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h\to0}\left[\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}-\frac{f(c-h)-f(c)}{h}\right]$$
and make a change of variable $(-h)\mapsto h$ in the second limit (I mean, in the second fraction).